# Understanding static methods inside the Validation class in angular4

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms, angular-validation, angular-validator

i am starting to learn model driven forms in angular and when i was going through the documentation of the model driven forms i found this

component.ts

```
 this.myForm= this.fb.group({
      'contact':['',Validators.required]
    });
```

now when i went to the definition of the validator class i found this

```
export declare class Validators {
...
static required(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null;
...
}
```

which explains **required is a static method** in the validator class and it requires a AbstractControl as a parameter. but why then i am allowed to use it without passing any parameter inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required method returns an error map with the 'required' property: `{'required':true}` if the value of `control: AbstractControl` is empty and `null` if its not.

.

**From the angular source code:** https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.9/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L133-L154

```
static required(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
    return isEmptyInputValue(control.value) ? {'required': true} : null;
  }
```

.

The reason why you can pass Validators.required without parenthesis and parameters is because Typescript is a superset of Javascript, which can store functions as variables:

```
var Foo = function (control: AbstractControl)
{
  return anyVal;
};
```

Is the same as:

```
Foo(control: AbstractControl): any
{
  return anyVal;
};
```

So doing this is completely valid

```
var Bar = Foo;
```

And because a function is just a variable holding executable code, we can store the function in multiple variables or pass it as a parameter, which is what is done in the FormControl.

So basically, when you do

```
const control = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

You are not executing the required method, because a method is executed only when parenthesis and parameters are added. Instead, you are passing the Validator function itself.

Comment: well my question is , why are we allowed to use like this 'contact':['',Validators.required] ? aint we suppose to use it something like this 'contact':['',Validators.required('')]